# Showing/hiding list items works in isolation, but not in site code

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I have a list of messages (a ul with a few li's) for which I'd like to show/hide as a fade-in/out marquee.

Easy enough:

```
    function InOut(elem) {
        elem.delay(100).fadeIn(1200).delay(10000).fadeOut(1200,

        function() {
            if (elem.next().length > 0) {
                InOut(elem.next());
            }
            else {
                InOut(elem.siblings(':first'));
            }

        });
    }

    $(function() {
        $('#myul li').hide();
        InOut($('#myul li:first'));

    });
```

This works in isolation the way I'd like (I've tweaked it in JSFiddle, and there was CSS, etc., involved).

However, when I put the code in my live site, it fails.  I placed the code just before the closing HEAD tag in case there was an "order" issue.

My suspicion is that the $(function()... is not taking effect.

The implementation is an IP Board site and the code is placed in one of the template files for the site.  Those template files are loaded with PHP calls, custom CSS for things, etc.  So, debugging is a bit of a nightmare.

I do not see any exceptions being thrown.

As I'm not familiar enough with javascript in this instance, I'm not sure what needs to be done here.  And I realize this might be tough without being able to share the page code (then again, could be really simple).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

/s/ Jon C. Munson II

Comment: here is the JSFiddle link to the working isolation case:  http://jsfiddle.net/LpAN3/29/

Comment: What do you mean debugging is a bit of a nightmare? If you have control over this code, you can use `console.log` to see how far your code gets. You can also check to see if things exist, such as `$("#myul")`. Is anything on your page loaded with AJAX? If so, then `$(function () {});` may not be the correct time to run your script.

Comment: I am sure that AJAX is used, so, is there a suitable replacement call?

Comment: So it's possible that AJAX loads the element `#myul`? If so, I'm not sure what you can do except poll for its existence...unless you can modify the code that actually inserts the `#myul`. The reason for your code possibly not working is that the AJAX may be run on load as well, but is asynchronous and takes some time, so the element(s) may not be appended until after your load script.

Comment: Ah, no the element '#myul' is not loaded by AJAX - that's a static page element in the template file.  Other elements may be loaded by AJAX, but naught to do with '#myul'.

Comment: Ahh okay, well is there any way you can use `console.log` to check the execution of your code?

Comment: I realize this is a fairly ignorant question, but, how does one do that?

Comment: lol... got it, I'll put it up...

Comment: Just put the call in various places throughout your code and provide an identifying string to print, then just check your browser's console :)

Comment: I put several calls to `console.log` - Before, After, inside, etc.  The only two that came up were before/after the declaration.  It never went into `InOut()`, nor inside the `$(Function...`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got this to work by these changes (some perhaps unnecessary):

```
            (function($){    
                 var InOut = function (elem) {
                      elem.delay(100).fadeIn(1200).delay(10000).fadeOut(1200,
                           function() {
                                if (elem.next().length > 0) {
                                     InOut(elem.next());
                                }
                                else {
                                     InOut(elem.siblings(':first'));
                                }
                           });
                  }
                  $(function(){
                       $('#ayeups li').hide();
                       InOut($('#ayeups li:first'));
                  });
             })(jQuery);
```

Thanks for everyone's looking, etc.  And thanks to @ianpgall for attempting to help. :D